# Finding a solution of a non-square linear system with SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, svd, pseudoinverse

According to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19767525/1422096), it seems that it's possible to find one solution of a non-square linear system that has infinitely many solutions with the following method.

1. Write the linear system as $A X = B$.
   (A is non invertible, since A is non-square)
2. Consider the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition) of $A$:

   $$A = U\  D\  ^t V$$

where $D$ is a $(m, n)$ diagonal matrix with non-negative real numbers on the diagonal.

3. Let $\Delta$ be a $(m, n)$ diagonal matrix, with:

   $\Delta_{i,i} = 0$ if $D_{i,i} = 0$
   $\Delta_{i,i} = \frac{1}{D_{i,i}}$ if $D_{i,i} \neq 0$
4. One solution of the initial linear system is given by:

$$ X= V\ \Delta\ ^tU\ B$$

**Is this true in general? (it seems to be true at least for [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19767525/1422096)). How can you prove this?**

---

Note: It seems that  $A^+ = V\ \Delta\ ^tU$ is the **pseudoinverse of the matrix $A$**, see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Obtaining_all_solutions_of_a_linear_system).

PS: [Here](https://www.ecse.rpi.edu/%7Eqji/CV/svd_review.pdf) are some ideas but I'm looking for a real proof.

---

Note2: It seems that this problem is in fact made of 2 steps:

1. Prove that if $A = U \Sigma ^tV$ is the SVD of $A$, then $A^+ = V \Sigma^+\, ^tU$ respects the conditions defining the pseudo inverse, i.e. $A A^+ A = A$, $A^+ A A^+ = A^+$, and the fact that $A^+ A$ and $A A^+$ are symmetrical matrices.
2. Prove that if $(1) A X = B$ has infinitely many solutions, then $X = A^+ B$ is a solution of (1), i.e. we have to prove that $A A^+ B = B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have the SVD $A=UDV^*$, with $U$, $V$ unitary, $D$ diagonal, then the matrix $V\Delta U^*$ (with $\Delta$ as in your post) *is* equal to the Moore-Penrose inverse of $A$: For instance
$$
A(V\Delta U^*)A = UDV^*(V\Delta U^*)UDV^*=UD\Delta DV^*=UDV^*=A,
$$
since $D\Delta D=D$. All other properties can be verified similarly.

If $Ax=b$ is solvable, i.e., there is $x_0$ such that $Ax_0=b$, then $A^+b$ is a solution:
$$
A(A^+b) = AA^+Ax_0 = Ax_0=b
$$
by the properties of the Moore-Penrose inverse.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s follow your links shall and consider all matrices over a field $K$ of real or complex numbers.

Let a $m\times n$ matrix $A$ has a singular-value decomposition $A=UDV^*$. Then 
the pseudoinverse $A^+$ of the matrix $A$ is $VD^+U^*$, where $D^+$ is the pseudoinverse of $D$, which is formed by replacing every non-zero diagonal entry by its reciprocal and transposing the resulting matrix (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition#Applications_of_the_SVD)). That is, $D^+=\ ^t{\Delta}$.

Since we have assumed that a linear system $Ax=b$ has (infinitely many) solutions, they are all given by $x=A^+b+[I-A^+A]w$ for arbitrary vector $w$, (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Obtaining_all_solutions_of_a_linear_system)). That is $x=VD^+U^*b+[I- VD^+U^*A]w$. In particular, if $w=0$ then $x=VD^+U^*b$.

Comment: Thanks. You have clearly reformulated the question, but there is no proof (that was what I was looking for). e.e. we have to prove that if we have a SVD decomposition of A, then $VD^+U^*$ is a pseudoinverse of A.

Comment: `Since we have assumed [...], they are all given by [...]`: the goal of my question is precisely a proof of this assertion. No demonstration is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Obtaining_all_solutions_of_a_linear_system).

Comment: @Basj There are given references to James’ [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3617665).

Comment: @Basj We can straightforwardly check that the matrix $VD^+U^*$ satisfies [Properties 1-4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Definition), which uniquely determine the pseudoinverse $A^+$.

Answer (score 0):

Additional notes to @daw's answer:

If $AX=B$ has infinitely many solutions, the set of solutions is exactly:

$$\Big\{ A^+ B + [I_n - A^+ A]w,\ \rm{ with }\ \ w \in \mathbb{R}^n \Big\}$$

**Proof:**
As mentioned by @daw, since we assume that there are solutions, there exists a $X_0$ such that $A X_0 = B$.

Now let $X_1 = A^+ B + [I_n - A^+ A]w$, for any vector $w$. Then: 
$$\begin{align}A X_1 &= A A^+ B + A [I_n - A^+ A]w \\ &= A A^+ A X_0 + A w - A A^+ A w \\ &= A X_0 + Aw - Aw \\ &=B  \end{align}$$

so $X_1$ is indeed solution of $A X = B$.

Conversly, let's assume $X_2$ is a solution of $AX=B$. Then:
$$X_2-A^+B=X_2-A^+AX_2 = (I_n - A^+ A) X_2$$ so, with $w=X_2$, we have:

$$X_2=A^+B+ (I_n - A^+ A) w.$$